# Setting GameObject position makes crash Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a script, I instantiate a GameObject.

```
float x = Random.Range(-cameraWidth / 2, cameraWidth / 2);
float y = Random.Range(-cameraHeight / 2, cameraHeight / 2);

Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);

GameObject newCar= Instantiate(car, position, Quaternion.identity);
```

The problem is that this code makes crash my engine.

I found out that the problem was my vector when I tried to instantiate it at another point with:

```
GameObject newCar = Instantiate(car, new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
```

And I also tried to set the instantiated object position to the vector *position*:

```
newCar.transform.position = position;
```

But it also crashed.

What is the problem with this vector? I debugged it and the values were correct.

Comment: What error do you get? I think, `newCar.transform` is `null`

Comment: Where do you create the car passed as parameter in method Instantiate?

Comment: Try

GameObject newCar = Instantiate(car, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

Comment: That does exactly the same as the line the OP posted. Vector3.zero is shorthand for new Vector3(0,0,0)

Comment: I do not get any errors since unity crashes. The GameObject is set from the inspector. I know Vector3.zero will work, what I want is that the car’s position equals to my Vector *position*